# postgresql how can i minus 5 minutes in date

Tags: postgresql

I want this time minus 5 minutes

I tried current_date but it gives me an other time than cet.

I need to get current date minus 5 minutes in postrgesql

```
SELECT now()  AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Brussels' AS europe ;
```

Comment: `now() - interval '5 minute'`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to substract/add minutes from a timestamp in postgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173732/how-to-substract-add-minutes-from-a-timestamp-in-postgresql)

Comment: SELECT now()- interval '5 minute'  AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Brussels' AS europe ; it gives me this error:ERROR:  no existe la función pg_catalog.timezone(unknown, interval)
LINE 1: SELECT now()- interval '5 minute'  AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Brus..

Comment: this worked SELECT now()  AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Brussels' - interval '5 minute' AS europe ; thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Brussels' - INTERVAL '5 minutes';
```

Produces:

```
┌───────────────────────────┐ 
│          column           │ 
├───────────────────────────┤ 
│ 2021-03-24 12:16:55.94187 │ 
└───────────────────────────┘
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html